# Ensure Optaplanner finds complete solution within time limit

Tags: optaplanner

I am using Optaplanner 6.3.0 to solve TSPTW problems in a user facing application. The number of visits is variable (based on user input) but less than 500. I would like to return an answer within a fixed time limit.

I currently have a secondsSpentLimit termination but have observed that when this termination occurs in the construction phase, the best solution is incomplete as not all visits are in the chain.

I want to ensure a complete solution, even a poor one, is always returned. I've considered, as a possible fix, initializing the starting solution myself and leaving off the construction phase. Would this work or is there a better way to achieve this?

Here is my current configuration:

```
<solver>
  ...
  <termination>
    <secondsSpentLimit>30</secondsSpentLimit>
  </termination>
  <constructionHeuristic>
    <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
  </constructionHeuristic>
  <localSearch>
    <unionMoveSelector>
      <changeMoveSelector>
        <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
        <selectionOrder>SHUFFLED</selectionOrder>
      </changeMoveSelector>
      <tailChainSwapMoveSelector />
      <subChainChangeMoveSelector>
        <subChainSelector>
          <maximumSubChainSize>50</maximumSubChainSize>
        </subChainSelector>
        <selectReversingMoveToo>true</selectReversingMoveToo>
      </subChainChangeMoveSelector>
    </unionMoveSelector>
    <acceptor>
      <lateAcceptanceSize>200</lateAcceptanceSize>
    </acceptor>
    <forager>
      <acceptedCountLimit>1</acceptedCountLimit>
    </forager>
    <termination>
      <unimprovedStepCountLimit>100</unimprovedStepCountLimit>
    </termination>
  </localSearch>
</solver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Partitioned Search with a nested CH does wonders to speed up the CH on big cases (at the expense of solution quality. Although if 30sec is too little for 500 entities, you want to check your score calculation speed first.

Nearby selection with limited selection is an alternative.

You can also add a CustomPhase.